# killing remote browser process from Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to close all open browser processes on the remote machine before running a Selenium test against it.

I used this line of code:

```
 @BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {

    WindowsUtils.killByName("iexplore.exe");
}
```

But it works when I am running locally on my computer and not on the remote computer.

Could anyone explain how I could get it to work on a remote machine?

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the `WebDriver` interface, `quit` method, which will close the driver.

Answer (score 0):

[`WindowsUtils.killByName()`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.java) simply execute locally the `taskill` command. That command runs locally, so no, it will not kill browsers on a remote server. You should make sure that all your tests use [`WebDriver.quit()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit()) to leave the environment in a consistent state, but I don't think there is an easy way to do mroe than that.